# YUICompressor unescapes backslashes

Tags: java, javascript, yui, minify, tapestry

In our application, we invoke YUICompressor to minify our javascript.  Under some conditions we are having trouble identifying, it incorrectly unescapes backslash-escaped characters, so for example

```
var newline="\n"
```

becomes

```
var newline="
"
```

has anyone seen this before, and do you know why it happens and how to make it stop?

Oh yes - this in the context of a Tapestry application, which may be related, since we can't reproduce the problem on the command line (using java -jar yuicompressor.jar...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We now think this may be fixed by upgrading to a newer YUICompressor - version 2.6 I think

Answer (score -2):

Did you try to use the inverted comma instead of the double quote?

```
var newline = '\n';
```